# Find selected words from Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find selected words from Word document using Word VBA but I'm getting stuck e.g. "25to30" anysuggestions below are the code used in wordvba

```
Selection.find.Execute FindText:="([0-9]{1,})([To])([0-9]{1,})", MatchWildcards:=False, Forward:=True
```

Comment: (To) not ([To]) and MatchWildcards:=True.

Comment: not working....

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: Note that if you are on a non english Word your delimiter might not be `,` but `;` then try `[0-9]{1;}to[0-9]{1;}` and `MatchWildcards:=True` also not that this is case sensitive when you look for `To` it won't find `25to30` because you look for a capital `T` and not a lower case `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Dpedending on whether there is a space either side of 'To':

```
FindText:="(<[0-9]@)(To)([0-9]@>)
```

or

```
FindText:="(<[0-9]@)( To )([0-9]@>)
```

And, unless you're going to do something with the individual components of what you find, there's no point having the parentheses.